# Re-using backbone routes, models, and views on the node.js server

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I am trying to build an application which both works as a SPA and as a normal application without re-writing any of the code as much as possible. My research has led to believe that this could be very possible using node + backbone (on both the server and client). I have found some resources on how to do this but nothing truly complete. Have anyone tried a full solution to re-using all the code?

The resources that I found:
Re-using backbone models on the server: http://blog.andyet.com/2011/feb/15/re-using-backbonejs-models-on-the-server-with-node/

Re-using backbone views and layout manager on the server:
http://vimeo.com/46033641

I have also found some frameworks that achieve this such as (bones, derby, meteor), but I dont feel like using such a framework is the best solution since I still want to have full control over backbone and node.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. Why do you want to use Backbone.Router on the server, though?

Comment: assuming that we manage to use backbone models and backbone-layoutmanager on the server then the both the backbone router and the node router would have redundant code since both routers would render the same views. so why use two routers instead of one?

Comment: Valid point. I just don't realistically see that you can use the same router code anyway. I would personally share some route hash -> view map but implement different routing mechanisms. Maybe your case is different though.

Comment: I didnt think about sharing a route hash -> view map but still it is redundant code since both the server and client would be using the same layout manager backbone-layoutmanager (Which works in node) so theoretically the same rendering code would exists in both routers. I am not 100% sure of this though im new to both node and backbone

Comment: Also +1 as writing similiar code on both client and server becomes a nightmare to maintain. Anyway [**this article**](http://nerds.airbnb.com/weve-launched-our-first-nodejs-app-to-product) is extremely interesting. I believe they will be open sourcing their library called Rendr pretty soon.

Answer (score 6):

What you are trying to implement is `Resource-View-Presenter` model. Please read this article completely http://blog.nodejitsu.com/scaling-isomorphic-javascript-code. It provides much needed insight for isomorphic code that can execute both on the client and the server. It also helped me understand various models and architectures.

What backbone.js uses is traditional MVC framework, which cannot work on both client and server without modifications. So if you want to stick to backbone.js you will face this disadvantage sooner or later. I tried backbone too and found no easy way to do that.

I tried looking for RVP frameworks on node.js, but it is still new. I would suggest you look into flatiron.js http://flatironjs.org/. It is based on Resource-View-Presenter model, the only one I could find for node.js. Some changes will be required to implement on both server/client, but it is not much. You will find it is similar to backbone.

Hope it helps you to find the right path.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. One thing needs clarification, though: Backbone is not a traditional MVC framework as it doesn't have separate controllers (the "C" in MVC).

Answer (score 5):

I recently did some research on the field and found some interesting projects that are using the same backbone code on the client and server (nodejs).

### Project 1

The first one was introduced by Keith Norma from Groupon. He managed to reuse backbone router + templates on the client and server.

App demo: https://github.com/keithnorm/SpainJS-Pipedream-Demo

Presentation at SpainJS talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbn9c_yfuoM

### Project 2

The second project is Rendr presented by Spike Brehm from Airbnb but not released yet to the public. It seems a bit more ambitious as it also trades backbone model and collections to the nodejs server. You can read more about it here: http://nerds.airbnb.com/weve-launched-our-first-nodejs-app-to-product

**UPDATE**: Rendr code has been released: https://github.com/airbnb/rendr

### Project 3

There is another project that also allows to share backbone code between client and server: https://github.com/developmentseed/bones